# Embedd StackView in ScrollView that is embedded in a main StackView

Tags: ios

Embedd StackView in ScrollView that is embedded in a main StackView

I am having trouble with a rather complicated detail view that I want to do programmatically. My view hierarchy looks something like this:

Since this might be better explained visualising, I have a screenshot here:
[image]

My problem is that I don't know how to set the height constraint on `descriptionTextView` – right now it's set to 400. What I want though is that it takes up all the space available as the middle item of the main stack view. Once one or more comments are added to the `contentStackView`, the text field should shrink.

I am not sure which constraints for which views I must set to achieve this...

Here's my take on it so far:

```
import UIKit

class DetailSampleViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var mainStackView: UIStackView = {
        let m = UIStackView()
        m.axis = .vertical
        m.alignment = .fill
        m.distribution = .fill
        m.spacing = 10
        m.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        m.addArrangedSubview(titleTextField)
        m.addArrangedSubview(contentScrollView)
        m.addArrangedSubview(footerStackView)

        return m
    }()

    lazy var titleTextField: UITextField = {
        let t = UITextField()
        t.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        t.placeholder = "Some Fancy Placeholder"
        t.text = "Some Fancy Title"

        t.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return t
    }()

    lazy var contentScrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let s = UIScrollView()
        s.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        s.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag

        s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        s.addSubview(contentStackView)

        return s
    }()

    lazy var contentStackView: UIStackView = {
        let s = UIStackView()
        s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        s.axis = .vertical
        s.alignment = .fill
        s.distribution = .equalSpacing
        s.spacing = 10
        s.contentMode = .scaleToFill

        s.addArrangedSubview(descriptionTextView)
        s.addArrangedSubview(getCommentLabel(with: "Some fancy comment"))
        s.addArrangedSubview(getCommentLabel(with: "Another fancy comment"))
        s.addArrangedSubview(getCommentLabel(with: "And..."))
        s.addArrangedSubview(getCommentLabel(with: "..even..."))
        s.addArrangedSubview(getCommentLabel(with: "...more..."))
        s.addArrangedSubview(getCommentLabel(with: "...comments..."))
        s.addArrangedSubview(getCommentLabel(with: "Some fancy comment"))
        s.addArrangedSubview(getCommentLabel(with: "Another fancy comment"))
        s.addArrangedSubview(getCommentLabel(with: "And..."))
        s.addArrangedSubview(getCommentLabel(with: "..even..."))
        s.addArrangedSubview(getCommentLabel(with: "...more..."))
        s.addArrangedSubview(getCommentLabel(with: "...comments..."))

        return s
    }()

    lazy var descriptionTextView: UITextView = {
       let tv = UITextView()
        tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
        tv.clipsToBounds = true
        tv.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        tv.layer.borderWidth = 0.25

        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        tv.text = """
        Some fancy textfield text,
        spanning over multiple

        lines

        ...
        """

        return tv
    }()

    lazy var footerStackView: UIStackView = {
        let f = UIStackView()
        f.axis = .horizontal
        f.alignment = .fill
        f.distribution = .fillEqually

        let commentLabel = UILabel()
        commentLabel.text = "Comments"

        let addCommentButton = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system)

        addCommentButton.setTitle("Add Comment", for: .normal)

        f.addArrangedSubview(commentLabel)
        f.addArrangedSubview(addCommentButton)

        return f
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = . systemBackground

        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true

        view.addSubview(mainStackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            mainStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
            mainStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
            mainStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 12),
            mainStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -12),

            titleTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: titleTextField.intrinsicContentSize.height),

            contentStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentScrollView.leadingAnchor),
            contentStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentScrollView.trailingAnchor),
            contentStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentScrollView.topAnchor),
            contentStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentScrollView.bottomAnchor),

            descriptionTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400),
            descriptionTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStackView.leadingAnchor),
            descriptionTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStackView.trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Detail View"
    }

    func getCommentLabel(with text: String) -> UILabel {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.layer.borderWidth = 0.25
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        l.text = text
        return l
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want your description text view to have a minimum height and be scrollable? Or, do you want its minimum height to be based on its non-scrollable text?

Comment: Actually those are two very good questions... I guess a minimum height is reasonable once I have more than just one or two comments, basically I just want to fill the void as long as there are no comments at all. 
Once there are, I guess both the content scroll view _and_ the text view need to be scrollable (so that the existence of comments cannot be overseen by the user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, but a couple notes:

When using stack views - particularly inside scroll views - you sometimes need to explicitly define which elements can be stretched or not, and which elements can be compressed or not.

To get the scroll view filled before it has enough content, you need to set constraints so the combined content height is equal to the scroll view frame's height, ***but*** give that constraint a low priority so auto-layout can "break" it when you have enough vertical content.

A personal preference: I'm generally not a fan of adding subviews inside `lazy var` declarations. It can become confusing when trying to setup constraints.

I've re-worked your posted code to at least get close to what you're going for. It starts with NO comment labels... tapping the "Add Comment" button will add "numbered comment labels" and every third comment will wrap onto multiple lines.

Not really all that much in the way of changes... and I think I added enough comments to make things clear.

```
class DetailSampleViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var mainStackView: UIStackView = {
        let m = UIStackView()
        m.axis = .vertical
        m.alignment = .fill
        m.distribution = .fill
        m.spacing = 10
        m.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // don't add subviews here
        return m
    }()

    lazy var titleTextField: UITextField = {
        let t = UITextField()
        t.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        t.placeholder = "Some Fancy Placeholder"
        t.text = "Some Fancy Title"
        t.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return t
    }()

    lazy var contentScrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let s = UIScrollView()
        s.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        s.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
        s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // don't add subviews here
        return s
    }()

    lazy var contentStackView: UIStackView = {
        let s = UIStackView()
        s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        s.axis = .vertical
        s.alignment = .fill
        // distribution needs to be .fill (not .equalSpacing)
        s.distribution = .fill
        s.spacing = 10
        s.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        // don't add subviews here
        return s
    }()

    lazy var descriptionTextView: UITextView = {
        let tv = UITextView()
        tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
        tv.clipsToBounds = true
        tv.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        tv.layer.borderWidth = 0.25

        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        tv.text = """
        Some fancy textfield text,
        spanning over multiple lines.

        This textView now has a minimum height of 160-pts.
        """

        return tv
    }()

    lazy var footerStackView: UIStackView = {
        let f = UIStackView()
        f.axis = .horizontal
        f.alignment = .fill
        f.distribution = .fillEqually

        let commentLabel = UILabel()
        commentLabel.text = "Comments"

        let addCommentButton = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system)

        addCommentButton.setTitle("Add Comment", for: .normal)

        // add a target so we can add comment labels
        addCommentButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addCommentLabel(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        // don't allow button height to be compressed
        addCommentButton.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)

        f.addArrangedSubview(commentLabel)
        f.addArrangedSubview(addCommentButton)

        return f
    }()

    // just for demo - numbers the added comment labels
    var commentIndex: Int = 0

    // do all this in viewDidLoad(), not in loadView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = . systemBackground

        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true

        title = "Detail View"

        // add the mainStackView
        view.addSubview(mainStackView)

        // add elements to mainStackView
        mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(titleTextField)
        mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(contentScrollView)
        mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(footerStackView)

        // add contentStackView to contentScrollView
        contentScrollView.addSubview(contentStackView)

        // add descriptionTextView to contentStackView
        contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(descriptionTextView)

        // tell contentStackView to be the height of contentScrollView frame
        let contentStackHeight = contentStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentScrollView.frameLayoutGuide.heightAnchor)
        // but give it a lower priority do it can grow as comment labels are added
        contentStackHeight.priority = .defaultLow

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain mainStackView top / bottom / leading / trailing to safe area
            mainStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
            mainStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
            mainStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 12),
            mainStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -12),

            // title text field
            titleTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: titleTextField.intrinsicContentSize.height),

            // minimum height for descriptionTextView
            descriptionTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 160.0),

            // constrain contentStackView top / leading / trailing / bottom to contentScrollView
            contentStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentScrollView.topAnchor),
            contentStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentScrollView.leadingAnchor),
            contentStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentScrollView.trailingAnchor),
            contentStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentScrollView.bottomAnchor),

            // constrain contentStackView width to contentScrollView frame
            contentStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentScrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor),

            // activate contentStackHeight constraint
            contentStackHeight,

        ])

        // during dev, give some background colors so we can see the frames
        contentScrollView.backgroundColor = .cyan
        descriptionTextView.backgroundColor = .yellow

    }

    @objc func addCommentLabel(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        // commentIndex is just used to number the added comments
        commentIndex += 1

        // let's make every third label end up with multiple lines, just to
        // confirm variable-height labels won't mess things up
        var s = "This is label \(commentIndex)"
        if commentIndex % 3 == 0 {
            s += ", and it has enough text that it should need to wrap onto multiple lines, even in landscape orientation."
        }
        let v = getCommentLabel(with: s)
        // don't let comment labels stretch vertically
        v.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        // don't let comment labels get compressed vertically
        v.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(v)

        // auto-scroll to bottom to show newly added comment label
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
            let r = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: self.contentScrollView.contentSize.height - 1.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
            self.contentScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(r, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func getCommentLabel(with text: String) -> UILabel {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.layer.borderWidth = 0.25
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        l.text = text
        // allow wrapping / multi-line comments
        l.numberOfLines = 0
        return l
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this looks awesome . Have been busy implementing a solutions that works for me right now (by calculating the height of `descriptionTextView` in `viewDidAppear` (that late cause it seems as though only the the needed heights of other objects are available...) – but your solution is wayyyyy more elegant! Will go ahead and refactor to your solution when I get time to do it. Thanks a ton so far; will mark answer as soon as I can confirm fully that it works.

Comment: Can confirm that this is now working as I expect it, thanks again.